# Converting cell colors to data: something like reverse conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet where each cell in the range A1:D20 is filled with one of 3 colors (Red, Green, Blue).

Without resorting to VB, is it possible to use some Excel formulae to convert all the cells to  a plain white background, with contents being 1,2 or 3 depending on what the original background color was? (ie, Red, Green or Blue)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Easily done with Vba, impossible with Formulas.

Can be done with `Find, Replace` one color at a time, by setting Find Format and Replace Foramt and value

Comment: had never noticed that you could search for formating.  thanks!